# Bulk update with inner join causing cpu high usage

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am running a query on my database

```
UPDATE oc_product
INNER JOIN mapprice on mapprice.UPC_Code = oc_product.upc
SET oc_product.price = mapprice.MAP_Price;
```

where `mapprice` has around 60k records and consist of the two fields and `oc_product` has over 250k

When I view the current mysql processes I get :

> Waiting for table level lock |
>
> SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer,
>   (SELECT price FROM oc_product_d |

And my CPU usage sky rockets.

Any help with making this query run faster would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My debugging approach would be:

- Check if `mapprice` has triggers that could be affecting performance.
- Make sure `mapprice.UPC_Code` and `oc_product.upc` has Indexes.

Comment: theres no triggers, and i have added idexes to those columns and it seems like its still doing the same thing. i was wondering if i could update lets say 1000 records at the time is that possible?